# feathers.js subscription behavior on patch/update

Tags: feathersjs

I am currently playing around with feathers to see if its a good replacement for meteor.js in our POS back-office application.
It looks really great so far but i cam up with a thing i could not solve.
Sometimes i miss a simple thing if i do not find something on the net but I hope someone can help me to figure out:
The problem:

I am using feathers client and a observable client side to populate a data-grid with documents from the mongoose/mongodb based service. It works fine beside I make an UPDATE/PATCH on ANY of the documents contained in the "table".

That moment all (filtered) find results are replaced by just this updated document.
I know that i could cache the results in an array and then use the respective events to update the array, but i wonder if there is an easier way (as in meteor) that the find result remains intact and if it contains the updated document that is simply updated.

Any help appreciated

Greets from Manila

Ralph

Comment: Please don't post walls of text, I edited your question to give it a slightly more appropriate form

Answer (score 2):

How to keep the data up to date depends much on the frontend framework you are using.

- The most framework agnostic solution is [feathers-reactive](https://github.com/feathersjs/feathers-reactive) which uses RxJS and works well with React (see [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IOwilPI4LFg)) and Angular 2+
- [feathers-vuex](https://github.com/feathersjs/feathers-vuex) for VueJS
- [can-connect-feathers](https://www.npmjs.com/package/can-connect-feathers) for CanJS

For everything else you can keep the data up to date manually through the [real-time events](https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/events.html) as you already mentioned.

Comment: I use angular 4. Also reviewed your video.
The problem is, that OTHER concurrent users only receive the updated row on patch, so their Observable bound to the data-grid only contains that one record.
Thanks and Greets

Comment: No. The point of feathers-reactive is to keep the entire list updated. The most common issue for what you are seeing is that the `idField` hasn't been configured properly.

Comment: Thanks very much. That works like a charm. I use ALWAYS as list strategy so my original query will be re-executed incl sort and paging.